# XSLT - merge nodes and remove duplicates - is this feasible?

Tags: xslt

```
XSPT experts, can you please guide on the following requirement?
Source XML file:
<root>
  <G1>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>1</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <G1>
  <G1>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>2</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <G1>
  <G2>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>1</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <G2>
  <G2>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>3</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <G2>
  <G3>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>1</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <G3>
<root>
```

Have a requirement to get all unique EMPLOYEE_IDs and print as flat file pipe delimitted as follows. We have 3 unique IDs 1,2 and 3. ID -1 is common for G1,G2 and G3 and print it for all groups. ID -2 is for G1 alone and ID -3 is for G2 alone and print those.

G1|1|
G2|1|
G3|1|
G1|2|
G2|3|

To achieve this, have to merge G1, G2 and G3 and remove duplicate value
for each unique Employee IDS [ 1,2,3 ]

```
  var current_employee select="Employee ID[$index]"
  for each G1[EMPLOYEE = $current_employee ]
   <xsl:text>G1</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="EMPLOYEE_ID"/>


  for each G2[EMPLOYEE = $current_employee ]
   <xsl:text>G2</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="EMPLOYEE_ID"/>

  for each G3[EMPLOYEE = $current_employee ]
   <xsl:text>G3</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="EMPLOYEE_ID"/>
```

How to get unique values of Employee IDs from the groups G1, G2 and G3 and store in Array to run a loop as mentioned above?

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. Then,  if you have a specific question ...

Comment: Please always say which version of XSLT you are using. Solutions to grouping questions are going to be very different between 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Sorry Michael for delayed response. It is XSLT 2.0.